# add quotes to words matching regex in file awk or sed

Tags: regex, sed, awk, quotes, vi

I want to add quotes to words in file matching particular regex using any tool, maybe vi, awk or sed. File contain many lines like this.

take this line for example::

```
'SellerName',2013-08-20 17:19:49,71.185.24.60,-8523106007192903367,5526150741,1,null,25d20a500342-653AC57AF9E6401B,16,2574455867,product description,-8574103407192903368,353860,_,null,-1
```

I would like to put single quotes around IP (`71.185.24.60`) and around the session id (`25d20a500342-653AC57AF9E6401B`).

I looked into awk, sed and vi but could not find how to insert matched-patterns in the substitution.

Let me know if you have some way to do it.

Comment: `matching particular regex` -- tell us your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward with awk:

```
awk '{ $3 = q $3 q; $8 = q $8 q } 1' FS=, OFS=, q=\' infile
```

This tells awk that the input and output are comma separated (`FS=, OFS=,`) and assumes that none of the fields contain embedded commas. Field 3 and 8 receive quotes through the `q` variable.

Output:

```
'SellerName',2013-08-20 17:19:49,'71.185.24.60',-8523106007192903367,5526150741,1,null,'25d20a500342-653AC57AF9E6401B',16,2574455867,product description,-8574103407192903368,353860,_,null,-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i s/71.185.24.60/"'71.185.24.60'"/g filename
```

Similarly for the other pattern.